# Redirect to user page after ajax sign in

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have problems having user redirected to his own page after he sign in.

I am using RAILS 4 and Ajax to handle that.

My login form:

```
   <%= form_for(resource,:html => {"data-parsley-validate" => true},:'data-parsley-validate' => true,:class=>"new_user",:id=>"new_user",:remote=> true,format: :json,as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.email_field :email,:class=>"user-input form-control" ,:id=>"user-name" ,:placeholder=>t('username'), autofocus: true ,required: true%>  
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.password_field :password,:class=>"user-input form-control", :id=>"password", :placeholder=>t('password'), autocomplete: "off",required: true %>
      </div>

    <span class="validation-message" style="color: white;"><%= t('incorect_password') %></span>

     <div class="remember-me">
       <div class="squared">
             <%= f.check_box :remember_me, :id=>"remember-me"%>                                     
                <label style="left: 0px;" for="remember-me"><span><%= t('remember_me') %> <!--Atcerēties mani --></span></label>                                        

        </div>
    </div>

        <%= button_tag t('login') ,:class=>"blue-button btn btn-default"   %>

         <%= link_to '#',:id=>"forgot-password-modal", :class => "pull-right forgot-pass" do %>

         <span><%= t('forgot_password') %></span>
            <% end %>
<%end%>
```

**Application controller:**

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

      if current_user.present? and current_user.role?(:advertisement)

         current_user.girl
      end
 end
```

**Problem:**

Ajax seems to work but the actual visualisation that login has been successful is only when I reload page. Then chrome message offering to save password is showed.

Can you please give me any advice ?

Thank You.

Comment: @Cyzanfar After I click login and if login is valid page should redirected to current user. But It doesnt...

Comment: meaning the user hasn't been signed in? and are you using Devise for user auth?

Comment: @Cyzanfar No, He is signed in but the page doesn't redirect, when I manually reload page it shows that I am signed in.. I want to achieve that page automaticaly redirects to desired page .

Comment: ok. Show us the controller action in charge of signing in a user. You may have a `sessions_controller.rb` file.

Comment: Also check out the [`sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, *args)`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers#sign_in_and_redirect-instance_method) Devise instance method

Comment: Why are you using an Ajax call?

Comment: @Raffael I want to get response on the same page if the password or username doesn't match.

Comment: Where are you calling Ajax? I can't find it on the code shown.